# Plotting Graph in Jenkins for individual test case execution time for all the builds

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, testng

I have to plot graphs in Jenkins which show the trend of builds comparing the test cases execution time. Suppose, every build has 2 test cases that are executed. I need to draw a graph in Jenkins which compares the execution time for the 1st test case for all the builds and similarly for the 2nd test case for all the builds.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this on my system yet.

You can try installing the Jenkins Plot plugin - https://plugins.jenkins.io/plot/

And to use this plugin, there's an article that you can refer - https://medium.com/@rachit.k.agrawal/how-to-configure-plot-plugin-in-jenkins-5b7ba81ce112